# Access merge fields from js script injection sidebar component

Tags: javascript, global-variables, sidebar

I have an HTML sidebar component that I'm using to inject js scripts in all standard pages. I need to be able to access global variables such as $User. How can I do this outside of a VF page?

So, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var prof = '{!$Profile.Name}';
        alert(prof);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is HTML content not Visualforce content so it does not go through any server-side processing such as expression replacement. So you cannot directly access Visualforce global variables.

However, it is possible to obtain server data by using [AJAX Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/apex_ajax.pdf) JavaScript calls such as `sforce.connection.getUserInfo` (that returns the profileID) and `sforce.connection.query`. See [Show and Hide Buttons on Page Layouts](http://www.tehnrd.com/show-and-hide-buttons-on-page-layouts/) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was trying to avoid an api call. Ok. Thank you for taking the time to answer @Keith